# Weierstrass-$\wp$ Function Asymptotics

Tags: special-functions, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

Given the Weierstrass-$\wp$ function,

$$\wp(2x+1+\tau \mid 1, \tau),$$

with half-periods $1$ and $\tau=\omega_2/ \omega_1$, I want to look at the case where $\rm{Re}(\tau) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and I want to look at the limits $\rm{Im}(\tau)>0$ both large and small.  Does anyone know of any asymptotics for these two limits?

I have been looking through Abrahmowitz and Stegun but can't find anything quite useful.